# How can I set up quota management for API products and configure a quota policy using OAuth 2.0 in Apigee?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, product, apigee

I want to achieve the following in **Apigee**.

1. Configure quota settings for **API products**.
2. Define and apply **quota policies** that align with **OAuth 2.0** authentication in Apigee.

Comment: 1/2: "1. Configure quota settings for API products" This is pretty straight forward. From Apigee edge dashboard -> Publish -> API Products -> Select a product -> Edit
Under edit, you should see an option to configure the quota value.
Note, doing this won't automatically impose quota on the APIs, you'll still need to add a quota policy to your proxy and use the context variables to read the values configured under the product.
Regarding "2. Define and apply quota policies that align with OAuth 2.0 authentication in Apigee." I don't follow your question.

Comment: 2/2: If that's not what you are looking for, please clarify what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To control how many times apps can access your API within a certain timeframe, Apigee lets you implement quota management using a [Quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/policies/quota-policy#overview) and OAuth 2.0. Here's how it works:

Define API Request Limits: Use the Quota policy to set a maximum number of requests allowed for a specific API proxy within a given time period (e.g., per minute, hour, or day).

Customize Quotas with Identifiers: Tailor limits for different apps or users by creating unique counters using flow variables and the [<Identifier>](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/policies/quota-policy#identifier) element within the Quota policy. This enables you to set different quotas based on criteria like client IDs.

Integrate with OAuth 2.0:

- Extract the client ID from validated OAuth 2.0 tokens using a JavaScript or Extract Variables policy.
- Pass this client ID to the Quota policy using a flow variable to link quotas to specific OAuth 2.0 clients.

Reference Default Settings: Streamline configuration by using the [<UseQuotaConfigInAPIProduct>](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/policies/quota-policy#usequotaconfiginapiproduct) element to leverage default quota settings defined in the API product itself.

Implement [Dynamic Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/policies/quota-policy#:%7E:text=/%3E%0A%3C/Quota%3E-,Dynamic,-quotas%20enable%20you): Create flexible quota systems based on user segments or other criteria using class-based quotas.

Remember:

- Apigee Edge tracks quota usage separately for each environment (test, prod, etc.).
- Thoroughly test quota policies to ensure they function as intended. Consider using
- Spike Arrest policies to protect against sudden traffic surges.